# How to launch multiple turtlebots in real environment?

Tags: ros, multiple, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to launch multiple turtlebots in real environment. In this scenario, there are several turtlebots and a remote workstation connected with each other. I want the robots to be controlled independently. I know how to revise the navigation and amcl launch files. But I don't know how to revise the minimal.launch file in turtlebot_bringup package of each robot to accomplish this. The ROS version I use is Indigo.Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228403/how-to-launch-multiple-turtlebots-in-real-environment?/) by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-05-05**:
hi, @Minglong, I ran into same problem. What @Mehdi suggests is the way to go, however, I can't get it to work with navigation stack. Therefore, I added new, more detailed [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/233674/launching-multiple-turtlebots-under-namespaces-real-environment/).

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-05-05**:
@Minglong, @Mehdi: I also added a [github repository](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_real_world) to try to reach a complete solution - try to see if it is useful for you, or if you can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this can be done by either having a roscore running on each Turtlebot laptop or by having one ROS core on your workstation and launching each Turtlebot on a different namespace such that all nodes and topics have a prefix like i.e turtlebot1/topic1 turtlebot1/node1

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0